# IBM Cloud Schematics: How do I upgrade the runtime from Terraform v0.12 to v0.13?

Tags: ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm, ibm-cloud-schematics

I am using IBM Cloud Schematics with a workspace based on Terraform 0.12. Based on the [changelog](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/schematics?topic=schematics-new-in-schematics) a new Terraform version is supported by the runtime. How do I change my workspace to use the new runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the below `versions.tf` file added to your repo. This should work for both Terraform version `0.12` and `0.13`.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    ibm = {
      source = "IBM-Cloud/ibm"
      version = ">= 1.12.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}
```

Also, the Terraform documentation on IBM Cloud covers the migration steps and also the  version control information [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-migration-versioncontrol)

Comment: I have seen it, but it applies to my local Terraform environment, not to that one managed by Schematics.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no automated migration, but the process is described in details here: [Migrating Terraform version in Schematics workspace](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/schematics?topic=schematics-migrating-terraform-version).

In short:

> The upgrade requires the following steps to support the latest Terraform version in the Schematics workspace.
>
> 1. Upgrade the Terraform configuration files to use the newer syntax and semantics.
> 2. Migrate the Terraform state file to be compatible with the newer version.

> Schematics does not support built in upgrade of the Terraform version. therefore, you must do the following:

> 1. Prepare the upgraded version of Terraform configuration files and Terraform state file, in your local machine.
> 2. Create a new Schematics workspace with the new Terraform configuration files and Terraform state file.
> 3. Delete the older workspace (without destroying the resources).